# Monitor ccmsetup.exe installation status usng powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

This question is realted to SCCM Client installer ccmsetup.exe. When we run manually ccmsetup.exe; it starts the installation process and exit from command prompt. I cannot monitor the installation process from commandline. It starts recording installation status in ccmsetup.log file. However time to execute completely varies per system.

How can I monitor ccmsetup.exe installation status using powershell.

I am using command as below:
Invoke-Command { C:\Client\ccmsetup.exe /Source:"C:\Client" SMSSITECODE=PPR FSP=Server1.ADDOMAIN.COM}

Thanks & regards,
Kedar

Comment: The problem with ccmsetup.exe is that the ccmsetup.exe process spawns a new process to do the actual install and exits. There are other issues where the install may require other components that require a reboot and it will wait for the reboot to continue. What I've done in the past is wait for the ccmexec.exe to show up, but you'll need to know your build process to understand if the install requires a reboot or not, and when to start monitoring for the file to show up.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same logic of presence of ccmexec and absence of ccmsetup. However this has few limitations on the final result of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot to the start-process cmdlet :

```
start-process C:\Client\ccmsetup.exe -ArgumentList @( '/Source:"C:\Client"' , "SMSSITECODE=PPR" ,  "FSP=Server1.ADDOMAIN.COM" -wait
```

And tell me it works, because it works for me :)

NB : the use a simple quotes allows double-quotes to be passed to the process launched.

Comment: This didn't worked for me. ccmsetup.exe dont wait till completion of the process.

Comment: Does your installer generate a logfile ? If Yes, there's a simple solution : checking the logfile for a string "Installation succesfull" ... That worked for me on a crappy installer ...

Comment: ccmsetup.log is the logfile you're looking for.  You might have success reading it with [Get-Content -wait](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/02/24/weekend-scripter-two-way-cool-powershell-text-file-tricks-tail-and-wait.aspx).